# How do I populate a SQL Arrays from rows in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays

I want to create an array in SQL Server and populate it using rows in a database table is this possible?

Comment: Can you give some more detail on what you're trying to achieve? You can create a table variable, but I'm not sure if this suits your needs.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have arrays - if you need to store any number of items, it's a **table** you're looking for ....

Comment: Did any of the suggestions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by doing like this:

```
DECLARE @List TABLE(ID VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @List
VALUES('a'),('10'),('20'),('c'),('30'),('d');
SELECT ID FROM @List;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support Arrays like other DBs does, like Oracle.

But you can achieve the same by creating separate Tables that will act like key-value pair and referencing them with the master table you are working with.

Erland has a good writeup on his blog/site regarding this topic, check here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented once like below :

```
declare @Array table(index int identity(1,1), value varchar(30));

insert into @Array (value)
select xyz from yourTable;

insert into @Array (value) values
('helloworld')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you could create a [Table Variable](http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx)...

```
DECLARE @TableName TABLE (column datatype)
INSERT INTO @TableName....
```

You could then use the table as a `JOIN` for example..

```
SELECT columns from TableA A INNER JOIN @TableName B ON A.Column = B.Column
```

You could also use a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)...

```
;WITH cteArray AS (SELECT Columns FROM SourceTable....)
SELECT columns from TableA A INNER JOIN cteArray B ON A.Column = B.Column
```

But this is obviously an assumption based on the lack of information in the question.  Also, if the query is straight forward, neither of these may be required, and a simple [*Subquery*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx) may be required.